# PHP check for valid function return

Tags: php, function, return

I have this code:

`$myVariable = someRanDomFunction($blah)`

The problem is that `someRanDomFunction()` might return an array, an object, an empty array, boolean value or NULL.

What if the best way to check that `$myVariable` has some data?

right now i'm doing this:

`!empty($myVariable )`

Will it cover all cases?
 or maybe i should do `($myVariable != NULL && !empty($myVariable ))`?

**UPDATE***

By 'some data' i mean `TRUE` if its bool, not empty array, and any value other than NULL

Comment: ...now first things first...when is the return value considered a 'failure'? Depending on the return value, you need to call a specific evaluation routine anyway, right? So why not check for `is_array` etc. manually, one after the other until you got it right?

Comment: Then !empty is exactly what you need ;)

Comment: Yes; empty. Nothing else. See my answer below what empty covers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var_dump(empty(NULL)); // returns bool(true)
```

empty is enough. If you say a boolean is no data, check also for !is_bool. (`empty(false)` returns also `true`)

Or better, use only `if ($result)`; this should be enough.

Or what do you call "some data"?

UPDATE: What you need:

> php > var_dump(!empty([]));
>
> > bool(false)
>
> php > var_dump(!empty(""));
>
> > bool(false)
>
> php > var_dump(!empty(false));
>
> > bool(false)
>
> php > var_dump(!empty(true));
>
> > bool(true)
>
> php > var_dump(!empty(null));
>
> > bool(false)

Answer (score 1):

Simply doing an implicit boolean check will exclude `false`, `array()`, and `null`.

```
if ($myVariable) {
    //will execute as long as myVariable isn't an empty array, false, null, or 0 / '0'
}
```

`!empty()` does exactly the same thing, with added suppression of warnings about undefined variables / array indices.  It's a little wordier, though.

Comment: `!empty('0') !== (bool)$myVariable`

Comment: @bwoebi - what are you talking about?

Comment: `[...] or 0 / '0'` in your inline comment. (you said empty would do the exact same thing)

Comment: Those both evaluate to false.

Comment: arrgh... I confused something... When I'm too blind to open the eyes and see the "!" on my command line....

Answer (score 0):

If you check for null, you need to use `!==` (strict checking http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 0):

If your someRanDomFunction might return an array, object, bool or null this is bad way. Something wrong with logic.

However you might using an **OR** (||) operator, not AND.

```
($myVariable != NULL || !empty($myVariable) || $myVariable == false)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you expect some specific data beforehand, it is better to check for it explicitly. PHP has a bunch of functions to do so they start with `is_`

Basically empty is checking for null, so your second way is redundant.
You can also use isset

Answer (score 0):

if the array, the object and boolean true is data AND The rest: an empty array, boolean false value or NULL, are not "data".

The solution then, would be this one:

```
$myVariable = someRanDomFunction($blah);

if(!empty($myVariable)) {
//...
}
```

Comment: What is "data" for you?  << Thread opener had updated his post